# I cannot display the linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem, I have created a new node.
And then I created a new node, to insert at beginning and show its display.
And then I created another node to insert it at the end but I cannot display it in the display function.
Can anyone tell me what's the issue here?
The display literally doesn't show up for the final linked list.

Here is the code :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void createlinklist();
void insertatfirst();
void insertatend();
void display();
struct node {
    int data;
    node * link;
};
node * start = NULL;
node * location = NULL;
void createlinklist() {
    node * temp = new node;
    cout << "Enter data in first node";
    cin >> temp -> data;
    temp -> link = NULL;
    start = temp;
    location = temp;
}
void insertatfirst() {
    node * temp = new node;
    cout << "Enter data for new node at the beginning ";
    cin >> temp -> data;
    temp -> link = NULL;
    start = temp;
    temp -> link = location;

    location = start;
    cout << "Linked first after inserting data at is ";
    while (location != NULL) {
        cout << location -> data;
        location = location -> link;
    }
    location = temp;
}
void insertatend() {
    node * temp = new node;
    cout << "Enter data for new node at the end ";
    cin >> temp -> data;
    temp -> link = NULL;
    location = start;
    while (location != NULL) {
        location = location -> link;
    }
    location -> link = temp;
    location = temp;

}

void display() {
    location = start;
    while (location != NULL) {
        cout << "The final linked list after ending at last node is ";
        cout << location -> data;
        location = location -> link;

    }
}

int main() {

    createlinklist();
    insertatfirst();
    insertatend();
    display();

}
```

Comment: You are not moving to the next element in your list in that display method of yours.
In fact, as long as there is at least one element in your list, you've got an infinite loop right there.

Comment: Sir, if I remove the insertion at end() function, the display does show up for insertion at first () function..
The display isn't showing for insertion at end...
Can you please fix this for me?

Comment: I have updated the code in the display function, but its still not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to follow some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) advice, and focus in on the problem as best you can.

Comment: You may want to look at one of the many posts regarding how linked lists are built. You've got the basic idea down, but a little searching will surely help you find some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is producing segmentation fault, look at these lines of code:

```
while (location != NULL) {
  location = location -> link;
}
location -> link = temp;
location = temp;
```

you are running the loop until `location` is `null` and then assigning `null -> link = temp` (as `location` is already `null`) this is what is causing a segmentation fault.

Change

```
while (location != NULL)
```

to

```
while (location -> link != NULL)
```

Everything should work fine after this.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! <3 I cant believe this..its working now